# Vim iabbrev in my vimrc does not work

Tags: vim

I am adding abbreviations in autocmds to my vimrc. They are as follows:

```
augroup caucmds
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c :iabbrev iff if ()<left>
    autocmd FileType c :iabbrev elseif else if ()<left>
    autocmd FileType c :iabbrev whilee while ()<left>
    autocmd FileType c :iabbrev elsee else ()<left>
    autocmd FileType c :iabbrev forr for ()<left>
augroup END
```

However they don't seem to work. Do I need to escape certain characters or something? Running them within a file on their own does not work either.

Comment: I don't think you need the colons.

Comment: Colons are optional there, yes.

Comment: Removing the colons seemed to fix it for the top one. However the others still don't work

Comment: Whats the output of `:autocmd caucmds` (Are the autocmds even being added properly)

Comment: It outputs them all properly

Comment: It seems to be working now...... O_o

Comment: Check if paste is set in your .vimrc file. comment if it is set `"set paste`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work, with or without the colons (they are redundant here).

You have installed these autocommands to trigger on the `FileType` event for the filetype `c`.

So, when you open any C file, you can type `iff<Space>` or `iff<Tab>` or `iff<Enter>` or `iff<Esc>` to trigger the abbreviation and insert the expansion. Note that the abbreviation only triggers after you have somehow indicated the end of it.

If the filetype `c` is not recognized for your C files, then you are probably missing the line

```
filetype plugin indent on
```

in your vimrc.

And you should use the non-recursive command `inoreabbrev` instead of `iabbrev`.

Comment: `filetype plugin indent on` is in my vimrc. Also, yes I am testing on a .c file

Comment: The remark about non-recursive mapping with `inoreabbrev` is very important. Please see [Steve Losh's comparison](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html) of recursive and non-recursive mappings for further explanation.

Answer (score 2):

They work great for me. But you should use  to do the abbreviations local to that buffer (you should that for everything that depends on a filetype). So, they result:

```
augroup caucmds
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType c :iabbrev <buffer> iff if ()<left>
    autocmd FileType c :iabbrev <buffer> elseif else if ()<left>
    autocmd FileType c :iabbrev <buffer> whilee while ()<left>
    autocmd FileType c :iabbrev <buffer> elsee else ()<left>
    autocmd FileType c :iabbrev <buffer> forr for ()<left>
augroup END
```

I've tried that and it works for me. Note that the abbreviations are not fired until you press a non-keyword letter. This is, for `iff` to fire you have to type `iff<space>`, for example. Note too that you must be editing a c file for them to work, as you have defined them only for c files.

If it still doesn't work, then perhaps you have some conflict. Try this to see who's last setting that abbrev:

```
:verbose iabbrev iff
```

Comment: The `:verbose ibbrev iff` returns "No abbreviation found", even after adding the <buffer> to each line

Comment: Yoy have a typo there (ibbrev instead of iabbrev). But I think that's a typo while copying it there. Then, are you on a c file when executing that? Execute `:set ft?` when that c file is open. If it doesn't say `filetype=c` at the status line, then you're not detecting filetypes. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes it is a c file. And I noticed the typo when Vim yelled at me :). It seems to be working now. I was resourcing my vimrc as I changed things so I don't know what the problem was. Thanks for your help! Upvoted